# list.gsp FileNotFoundException when following Grails scaffolding tutorial with app-engine plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, grails

I'm trying to follow the [grails tutorial here](http://grails.org/Quick+Start#Create%20a%20controller).

When I create a new controller using `create-controller XXX.Card` and modify it to use scaffolding as per the tutorial:

```
package XXX

class CardController {  
    def scaffold = Card
}
```

I get the following exception when I click on [XXX.CardController](http://localhost:8080/card):

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static XXX.Card.list() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[max:10, action:list, controller:card]]
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:342)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static XXX.Card.list() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[max:10, action:list, controller:card]]
    at XXX.CardController$_closure2.doCall(script1258397512682.groovy:14)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at XXX.CardController$_closure2.doCall(script1258397512682.groovy)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    ... 5 more
```

I'm using Grails 1.1.1 with the app-engine 0.8.5 and gorm-jpa 0.5 plugins.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the script I use to reproduce this problem:

```
rm -rf ~/.grails/1.1.1/projects/XXX
grails create-app XXX
cd XXX
grails install-plugin gorm-jpa
grails install-plugin app-engine # Note: specify JPA when prompted
grails create-domain-class XXX.Card
grails create-controller XXX.Card
cat > grails-app/controllers/XXX/CardController.groovy <<EOF
package XXX

class CardController {
    def scaffold = Card
}
EOF
cat > grails-app/domain/XXX/Card.groovy <<EOF
package XXX

class Card {

    List emails

    static hasMany = [emails:String]
}
EOF
grails app-engine
```

Comment: The URL you're trying to hit looks wrong... where is the project name in the URL?  It should be http://localhost:8080/project/card   shouldn't it?  Not that the bad URL should cause the error you're seeing, though, and the error message seems to show that you've actually got an XXX in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some conversations on the forums, it appears that GORM is only lightly working with App Engine at this time.  Until the next release of the various plugins involved (app-engine and gorm-jpa) it's probably best to stay away from GORM with App Engine.

- [Problem trying to use scaffolding with app-engine](http://old.nabble.com/Problem-trying-to-use-scaffolding-with-app-engine-td26356702.html)
- [New user grails+app-engine frustration](http://old.nabble.com/New-user-grails%2Bapp-engine-frustration-td26381616.html)

Thanks for all the help, Tomas.

Answer (score 1):

I just re-created your scenario with the following steps, using Grails 1.1.1:

```
grails create-app XXX
cd XXX
grails create-domain-class XXX.Card
grails create-controller XXX.Card
-- Edited grails-app\Controllers\XXX\Card.groovy removing the index action and adding the scaffold declaration "def scaffold = Card"
grails run-app
```

When I visited http://localhost:8080/XXX/card, I was given the appropriate list page for the Card class (which had no entries, and no columns, since I hadn't added anything to Card)

Note the lowercase "card" (you seem to have it correct), this is important.  Controller paths in the URL are defaulted to start with a lower case.

Hope this helps.  If you can't follow these steps and get it to work, I'd look at those plugins you installed.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing the gorm-jpa plugin? I don't think list() is implemented in the app-engine plugin, but rather in gorm-jpa.

jdo has no gorm support.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Good catch, I was missing that in my original.  I've rewritten the problem description to include that plugin, which doesn't seem to have solved the problem.  See above.